# Why are my DataGridViews inside the Tab Controls are not being affected by my code?

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 forms, the first form is for the button to trigger the code and the second form has the tabcontrol with 5 tab pages which will receive the code. Each one of the tab pages in the second form has 1 datagridview(so tab 1 contains datagridview1, tab 2 contains datagridview2 and so on. In the second form's form load, I populated each datagridviews:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Apple", "Orange")
me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add("Banana", "Strawberry")
me.DataGridView3.Rows.Add("Hotdog", "Burger")
me.DataGridView4.Rows.Add("Pizza", "Monkey")
me.DataGridView5.Rows.Add("Melon", "Lemon")
```

Now I want to clear all rows using the button from the first form:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button1.Click
Form2.DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
Form2.DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
Form2.DataGridView3.Rows.Clear()
Form2.DataGridView4.Rows.Clear()
Form2.DataGridView5.Rows.Clear()
Me.Hide()
Form2.show()
```

But it doesn't seem like it is working. Any idea why is that? 
Highly appreciated

Comment: Probably an issue with default/implicit form instances.  Forms are classes, so you should create instances of them and pass them as needed.

Comment: Where does button1 reside? You doing a Form2.Show after you clear so it's triggering the Form2_Load when is filling them back in.